# Will a laptop works with missing GPU Power rail?

Tags: buck, switching-regulator, motherboard, gpu

I have a skylake laptop with a dedicated graphics, the Mosfets on the buck converter are shorted (at least one of them) so if i cut the 1v gpu power rail will the laptop works again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already cur the rail, does it work? Why you are asking then?

Comment: I didn't cut the rail, the rail is shorted to ground (the mosfets on the Buck regulator) I'm asking if i remove these mosfets will the laptop works with the integrated gpu even though the 1V rail is missing?

Comment: It’s very unlikely that the output pins of the integrated graphics are connected anywhere.

Comment: I dont think this question is possible to answer with the limited information given. If you want your laptop to work, i would go with anonymous and take it to a repair person. How do you know the mosfet is shorted, and it isnt a different issue? it's likely impossible to tell unless you've taken the component out and tested it outside the circuit.

Comment: I have the schematics of the laptop, I tested the mosfets with a DMM, The 19v is shorted  to the 1v  rail and the DMM shows 20ohms between the 19v rail and ground, the power supply consists of a 3 phases back converter  (so there's 3 dual  mosfets). I want to know if removing these 3 dual mosfets Will cause an issue on the normal use of the computer (without the dGpu) or  not.

Comment: Why don't you just try? The laptop is already dead.. And now do you plan to reconnect the LCD LVDS dedicated signals from a GPU to something else, if you want "normal use" of the laptop? And just to set proper expectations, usually multi-rail computers have a thing called "power good", a signal which gets global status of all power supplies, so if one is gone, the computer won't start anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass your laptop to the knowledgeable and experienced service engineer, ideally from authorized service center. If you do anything to the laptop, there's a chance that it is noticed during repair and service center costs may soar.